# I've to show menu bar with stats like count of messages and updates, also other counts like gifts and messages count

Tags: yii

I want to show a menu bar with stats like count of messages and updates, also other counts like gifts, new friend request and messages count.

This menu will be displayed on the all the pages.
How can I write a single method to get all the stats and render partial into the layout and forget about it?

And in other action just concentrate on the main functionality of the page. Without bothering about the menu.

How can I achieve this in Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a widget. You could for example extend [`CMenu`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu) and do the queries in `init()` there:

```
<?php
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CMenu')
class MainMenu extends CMenu
{
    public function init()
    {
        // Do some count queries here. This is just an example,
        // your implementation will differ, of course:
        $newMessages = Messages::model()->new()->count();

        // Now add the menu items:
        $this->items = array(
            array(
                'label' => "$newMessages New messages",
                'url'   => array('messages/list'),
            ),
            // ...
        );

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

You then can use this widget in your `views/layouts/main.php`:

```
<?php $this->widget('MainMenu'); ?>
```

Comment: This is it... I was looking for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [beforeAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) to achieve this. 
As the docs say "This method is invoked right before an action is to be executed (after all possible filters.) You may override this method to do last-minute preparation for the action."

Also you can define public variables in you main controller (Components/Controller.php) so every other controller has access to these. You can then use them in your layout using $this-variable...

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends CMenu in /protected/components/extendingclassname

```
<?php
 Yii::import('zii.widgets.CMenu');

class Notifications extends CMenu
{
   public function init()
    {
      //query

    $requestor=Yii::app()->user->name; 
    $count = Requests::model()->count( 'requestor=:requestor',                        array('requestor'         =>      $requestor));

    // Now add the menu items:
    $this->items = array(
        array(
            'label' => "$count New messages",
            'url'   => array('user/notifications'),
        ),
        // ...
    );

    parent::init();
   }
 }

?>
```

Then include the following line within your /layouts.main.php.Hope this helps a beginner who is not sure where to use the class.That's something Michael Härtl forgot to mention.